# How to calculate memory occupied in stack and heap for a given program?

Tags: c#, memory-management

Is that possible to calculate the stack memory and heap memory occupied by a program in c#.net console application ?

Comment: For stack allocations you probably will need to look at the dump. WinDbg or Visual Studio can save a dump (make sure to pick correct option in WinDbg to get all stacks).

Comment: Actually what is your goal to look at the stack memory?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Memory profiler Tool`  in order to inspect your memory

link : http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=unmet_need&utm_campaign=antsmemoryprofiler&gclid=CNCauM7ehrYCFczHtAodwR4AJQ